# Video JS - Change Play Icon in ControlBar with Replay Icon After Video End

Tags: video.js

I have a videojs player. I want to chage play icon in controlbar with replay icon when the video has end.
You can see like youtube player :

[image]

This is my code :

```html
<script>
videojs("my_video_1").ready(function(){

var vid = this;
vid.on("ended", function(){
alert ("I want to change play icon in cotrolbar with replay icon");
 // i dont know to chage play icon when the video is finish

});

});
```

This is my full code. You can run it via jsbin: http://jsbin.com/fijefi/2/

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need javascript to do this. You can change the play icon via CSS.

In the default LESS file there are two states for the play button:

```
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-play-control:before {
  content: @play-icon;
}
.vjs-default-skin.vjs-playing .vjs-play-control:before {
  content: @pause-icon;
}
```

You just need to add a third state when the video has ended. There is already a CSS class for that. You'll end up with something that looks like:

```
.vjs-default-skin.vjs-ended .vjs-play-control:before {
   content: "YOUR REPLY ICON";
 }
```